# Using boolean-value of attributes in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a React.js project. I want to use data-picker plugin which require this style of input-attributes:

```
<input data-enable-time=true />
```

But webpack doesn't compile the app, when true is without quotes. Plugin doesn't work, when true with quotes.
What I should do?

UPD.

Yes, I run picker in componentDidMount()
It works, but displaying only date, without time.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
const Flatpickr = require('flatpickr');

export default class Date extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    let dateInput = document.getElementById('fPicker');
    //init picker
    new Flatpickr(dateInput);

  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="dateInputContainer">
        <input id="fPicker" className="flatpickr" data-enable-time="true" />
     </div>
    )
  }
}
```

But `data-enable-time="true"` doesn't work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the HTML spec, there is no difference between `data-enable-item=true` and `data-enable-item="true"`. They will function exactly the same in browsers. Because HTML attributes without quotes are practically never used and can lead to a number of issues, React always uses quoted attributes.

In the snippet below you can check that they do indeed have the exact same effect.

I suspect your plugin not working is probably because you are loading your plugin the wrong way, and not because of the data attribute style. Are you sure you're only starting the date picker after the component has been mounted (for example, in componentDidMount)?

```js
var withoutQuotes = document.getElementById('input-no-attribute-quotes');
var withQuotes = document.getElementById('input-with-attribute-quotes');

console.log('Are the data attributes for test exactly the same? ' + (withoutQuotes.dataset.test === withQuotes.dataset.test ? 'Yes.' : 'No.'));
console.log('Data attributes without quotes\n', withoutQuotes.dataset);
console.log('Data attributes with quotes\n', withQuotes.dataset);
```

```html
<input id=input-no-attribute-quotes data-test=true />
<input id="input-with-attribute-quotes" data-test="true" />
```

Comment: I suspect you have a different issue then, because flatpickr uses `dataset` to get the data attributes, and as you can see in my answer, the result of `dataset` is the same with and without quotes on `data-enable-time`.

Comment: @OP, please don't delete your comments after they've had responses. I've looked at the Flatpickr source for you and I think you should try `data-enabletime` instead of `data-enable-time`. Probably a bug in the library.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the right answer/comment as correct.

Answer (score 83):

You can just omit the value assignment; the attribute will be assigned a value of `true` by default.

Instead of doing any of:

```
<input data-enable-time=true />
<input data-enable-time='true' />
<input data-enable-time={true} />
```

Do:

```
<input data-enable-time />
```

This approach avoids the warning `Value must be omitted for boolean attributes [react/jsx-boolean-value]` when the code is linted via [eslint-plugin-react](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react).  (See: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-boolean-value.md)

Answer (score 9):

The answer is right over on this [github markdown](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-boolean-value.md).
My solution is writing your code in the style:

```js
<input data-enable-time /> /*treats as true*/
<input data-enable-time={false} /> /*treats as false*/
```

when you are going to specify a trueish attribute you should omit the value and when you are going to specify it `false` you shouldn't pass the attribute

Comment: What if we want to assign dynamically? I just want to achieve form validation and that is required to assign value dynamically

Comment: Hi @JaynaTanawala, if you want to assign a value dynamically you are going to need curly braces. ```<input data-enable-time={myDynamicValue} />```

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
<input data-enable-time={true} />
```

Comment: This produces warning `Value must be omitted for boolean attributes [react/jsx-boolean-value]` when the code is run through eslint-plugin-react. (See: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-boolean-value.md)

Comment: Then maybe this rule should be ignored

Answer (score 0):

i guess thats a loader problem,
Try to put

```
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
          plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-object-assign', 'transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators-legacy', 'transform-es2015-modules-commonjs-simple',],
        },


      },
      ...
    ],

  },
```

into your webpack.conf.js file
and install every plugin via npm

for example:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-react-html-attrs
```

Comment: Still not working.  You can see screenshot https://pp.vk.me/c626318/v626318440/1dadc/g8iAahZKmv4.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Tricky stuff.. I am always forgetting about this.
In this case just use:
`<input data-enable-time />`

Without assigning it to the boolean.